# I need to pull values from database and show parameters as dropdown in Jenkins parameterized job. Suggest a way to achieve this

Tags: database, jenkins

I need to pull values from database and show parameters as dropdown in Jenkins parameterized job.
After searching online I could see writing a groovy script is one way to achieve this but I couldn't find any reference of how to connect to database using groovy script.
Any thoughts on this would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can configure db client on Jenkins master, call it and parse the output. For example, I use a Groovy script below to populate a list of branches:

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote -h https://github.com/mtuktarov/active-choices-plugin").execute()
def objects = gettags.text.readLines().collect {
    it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '') 
}
return objects
```